# Give an argument using generating functions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, integer-partitions

Let $l_n$ be the number of partitions of $n$ which have exactly two parts of size $1$.
Let $L(x) = \sum l_n x^{n}$ be the generating function for $(l_n)$. (Let $l_0 = 1$ and $l_1 = l_2 = l_3 = 0.)$
Give an argument using only generating functions for why for $n \geq 3$,
$l_n = p_{n−2} − p_{n−3}.$ where $p_n$ is the number of partitions of $n$.

**Attempt**: 
I've tried drawing Ferrer's shapes but could not arrive at a conclusion. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'd think you would want $l_2 = 1$.

Comment: Is $p_n$ the number of partitions of $n$?

Comment: Yes. Sorry I should have clarified that.

Answer (score 1):

Let $P(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}p_nx^n$ be the generating function for the partition numbers. I expect that you know that

$$P(x)=\prod_{k\ge 1}\frac1{1-x^k}\;.$$

If we restrict ourselves to partitions that **don’t** have any parts of size $1$, the generating function becomes

$$P_{\ge 2}(x)=\prod_{k\ge 2}\frac1{1-x^k}\;;$$

we just lose the first factor. Thus, $P(x)=\frac1{1-x}P_{\ge 2}(x)$, and $P_{\ge 2}(x)=(1-x)P(x)$.

There is an easy bijection between the set of partitions of $n$ with exactly two parts of size $1$ and the set of partitions of $n-2$ with **no** parts of size $1$, so $\ell_n$ is the coefficient of $x^{n-2}$ in $P_{\ge 2}(x)$. That is the coefficient of $x^n$ in

$$x^2P_{\ge 2}(x)=x^2(1-x)P(x)=x^2(1-x)\sum_{n\ge 0}p_nx^n\;.$$

Move the factor of $x^2$ inside the final summation, and you’re almost there.

Comment: You could also view the restriction on parts of size 1 as replacing the factor $\frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \cdots$ with just $x^2$.